# Returning 0 when a negative value is encountered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I would like to return 0 if a certain value is negative.  I know I can achieve that in PHP by using the `max($value, 0)` function; is there a JavaScript or jQuery function that provides similar functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Math.max(value, 0)`.